# How to retrieve AccessToken and AccessTokenSecret values for Twitter programmatically in xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to retrieve AccessToken and AccessTokenSecret values programmatically in xcode.

I'm unable to get these values.

Here are the files which I'm referring:

FHSTwitterEngine, TwitterManager

Could anyone please suggest some solution?

Thanks!